# Open two sites when I click on link

Tags: jquery, click, window.open

I would like to kindly ask you for help with my coding. I am trying to use Java script on my websites but it is not doing exactly what I need.

Let me explain, how this code below works. When you open website with the code, nothing will happen, unless you click on any link on the site. After that link page is opened and right after new TAB opens as well with another website: http://your_adress.com . So in this phase you have two TABs opened, one what you wanted(link site) and one what you did not know (new TAB).

This situation happens everytime, you click on any link on website.

My question in here is: what I need to implement in my code, to make sure, that  website your_adress.com from code will be opened only once per session, not everytime when user click on some article. Its very annoying for user.

My 2 Q: what do I need to add to the code, so new website your_adress.com will be only in background, not as main page. I want user to check website your_adress.com after reading article on parent page, not before. For better explanation: User will stay on page which he opened, but second tab or window will be opened without immediate notice. I want user to notice after (like FB fan page).

Here is the simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).click(function() {
window.open(
"http://your_adress.thank_you",
"_blank"
);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your first question .. you need to read about cookies .. you can find it here

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

and the example for this you can find it here

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

for 2nd question .. there are more ways you can use

**1st:** `setTimeout();` by this way new window with new url will open after 5 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // open new window code here
} , 5000);
```

**2nd:** `.offset().top;` by this way when the user scroll reach to the end of article the new window will open

```
var Top_DIV_Next_Article = $("#DIV_next_article ").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > Top_DIV_Next_Article ) { //scrolled past the Top_DIV_Next_Article 
       // open new window code here // you need to use boolean in this case here to prevent the code open another new windows while scrolling
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: please read my next comment (answer). thanks for your help Mohamed

Comment: @Marian I've read it.. We trying harder here to solve your issue/errors .. and it'll be much better to see your related code in https://jsfiddle.net/ to know what you have trying so far .. the demo explain well what you trying to do .. then It'll be simple to you to get a better help .. but just take in consider no one can understand your project and what in your mind until you show him a related code/demo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I forgot to tell you, that I would like the pages to be open naturally, not after some time. I want to open them as native click.     My first Q was not well explains.Sorry for that. Right now code is working like each page is opened, each time we you will click on something and each time new window is opened. I dont want to use popup of pop down windows. It needs to be user native click.

Example: you will enter http://www.letstravel.cz page and after one click on link(or anywhere) you will be redirected on same page to link you click on. Additionaly, new tab will be opened with FB fan page. Same second, no timeout. The problem in here is, that after redirection, when you click on anything esle, you will get another FB fan page opened. So imagine openening 10 articles, 10 extra FB fan pages will be opened. I want to open 10 articles, with one time FB page. Per session (per browser is closed.)

Do I need to work with database somehow? Better if not. Or I can use something like this? I am real beginner in any coding.

collect IP adresses from visitors and count time.
    if($sql_ip_time+3600

I am not sure if approach is good or not.

2nd: I will try again to put example. We have 2 tab what we will be working with. First tab is an article /article.html. Second tab is not opened yet. I will click in TAB1 on link to article_2.html and with is TAB2 is opened with FB fan Page. What you see in your browser is TAB2 as primary. what you see is FB page, not TAB1. What I want to do is to click in TAB1 on link for article2 and read this article. By the time, new TAB2 will be opened with no notice. After closing all tabs, user will notice, that some FB fan page is opened.

I appreciate help in here really a lot. Without this forum I am lost. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Withmy friend we have created this code, but I am not sure what is wrong with it. I also want to set session cookies, but I dont know where to implement this:

```
document.cookie = "mtracker=somevalue; expires=0; path=/";
```

Here is the code itself and it should open new tab (not popup window) after clicking anywhere on page, but only open this facebook page once per 24 hours. I need to change 24 hours to session and also I am not sure what might be wrong with code. Can anybody please loook in my progress so far? Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript">
var urlForPopup = "http://www.facebook.com";

if(!wasPopupAlreadyDisplayed())
{
       var myWindow = window.open(urlForPopup, "_blank");
       setCookie("WasPopupDisplayed", "true", 1);      //expires in one day
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ", " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function wasPopupAlreadyDisplayed() {
    var wasDisplayed = getCookie("WasPopupDisplayed");
    if (wasDisplayed != "") {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
</script>
```